# How to activate all steps together in material-ui?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm using material-ui in my React project and now I want to show a stepper. but I dont want buttons for going backward and forward in steps. I want all steps to be active together.

```
import React from 'react';
import Stepper from '@material-ui/core/Stepper';
import Step from '@material-ui/core/Step';
import StepLabel from '@material-ui/core/StepLabel';
import StepContent from '@material-ui/core/StepContent';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';

function getSteps() {
  return ['Title 1', 'Title 2', 'Title 3'];
}

function getStepContent(step) {
  switch (step) {
    case 0:
      return `For each ad campaign that you create, you can control how much
              you're willing to spend on clicks and conversions, which networks
              and geographical locations you want your ads to show on, and more.`;
    case 1:
      return 'An ad group contains one or more ads which target a shared set of keywords.';
    case 2:
      return `Try out different ad text to see what brings in the most customers,
              and learn how to enhance your ads using features like ad extensions.
              If you run into any problems with your ads, find out how to tell if
              they're running and how to resolve approval issues.`;
    default:
      return 'Unknown step';
  }
}

class VerticalLinearStepper extends React.Component {

  render() {
    const steps = getSteps();

    return (
      <div className={classes.root}>
        <Stepper orientation="vertical">
          {steps.map((label, index) => {
            return (
              <Step key={label} active={true}>
                <StepLabel>{label}</StepLabel>
                <StepContent>
                  <Typography>{getStepContent(index)}</Typography>
                </StepContent>
              </Step>
            );
          })}
        </Stepper>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

what i want is to see all the steps contents together without any Button for going backward and forward. but I can only see the content of the first step because the default value for `activestep` prop of 'Stepper' is 0.

Comment: When you want all the content together then why do you need stepper?

Comment: My understanding is that a stepper is just what it sounds like; a stepper which means it is designed to always have one step active while the others not. It sounds like you're looking for something else. Maybe Tabs?

Comment: @Think-Twice because it's beautiful.@J.Lindebro  it's not tabs.what i want is to have 6 assignments with a title and a short description. I want to show them vertically from 1 to 6. and when a student completed one of them I will replace the number with a green check mark.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

adding active = {true} to the Step component solved this issue.

Answer (score 3):

adding expanded={true} to the Step solved this issue.

Answer (score 2):

Add `active` will highlight the step

Add `expanded` will expand the step

Combine them together
`<Step active expanded>`